# How to terminate previous build's process when running the project?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've just started using PyDev to work on a Flask app. The thing is, every time I make a change, I have to click on the "stop process" button in the console window, then click "Run" again.

This is necessary, because Flask runs a web server on a specific port, and running more than one instance of the application results in errors connecting to the port.

Is there a way I can automatize this process? (configuration, some sort of event handler, or any other way)

Comment: @Editor: I placed the tag `pydev` on the title because the tag bar said it didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign short cut key to `Terminate and Relaunch` command. Click `Windows > Preferences`. Then type **keys** in search box. Refer pic below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the PyDev editor you can use Ctrl+Shift+F9 to terminate/relaunch by default.

But as you're dealing with flask, you should be able to use it to reload automatically on code-changes without doing anything by setting use_reloader=True.

I.e.: I haven't actually tested, but its documentation says that you can set the reload flag for that run(use_reloader=True).